# AngularJS defer error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, runtime-error, promise, deferred

I'm attempting to make my app gather the data before changing the route, as shown on many a video from John Lindquist: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6KITGRQujQ&list=UUKW92i7iQFuNILqQOUOCrFw&index=4&feature=plcp

I have it all hooked up, but when it's time for the deferred object to resolve, i get the error:

```
Error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
at assertArg (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:1019:11)
at assertArgFn (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:1029:3)
at annotate (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:2350:5)
at invoke (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:2833:21)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:2874:23)
at http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:4759:24
at <error: illegal access>
at Object.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:8261:28)
at http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:7417:26
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:6797:59) angular.js:5704
```

My code looks like this:

Route -

```
angular.module( 'saApp' )
.config( function ( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {
    $routeProvider
        .when( '/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
            controller: Dashboard,
            resolve: Dashboard.resolve
        } 
});
```

controller -

```
var Dashboard = angular.module( 'saApp' ).controller(
    function ( $scope, dataset ) {
            $scope.data = dataset;
    } );

Dashboard.resolve = {
  dataset: function ( $q, DBFactory ) {

    console.log("dataset enter")
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    DBFactory.get( {noun: "dashboard"},
        function ( data ) {
            console.log("resolving");
            deferred.resolve( data );
        } );

    console.log("promise");
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

On run, it executes the resolve, the DBFactory resource goes, comes back and everything works up until the actual "deferred.resolve(data);"  which is where then i get the error pasted above. If i comment that one line out, of course i get no page, but i also get no error.

The contents of data, coming back from DBFactory is a JSON object, which is what is expected, and shown in all the examples i've seen online and videos.

using:

```
AngularJS 1.0.6
```

Thoughts? Thanks for all your help.

**UPDATE:**

It seems the way i was using my routes and defining the controller with the namespace:

```
var Dashboard = angular.module( 'saApp' ).controller()
```

was to blame for this. When i simply use a standard function declaration:

```
function DashboardCtrl($scope, dataset) {
  $scope.data = dataset;
}
```

it satisfies the "looking for function, got object" error. The weird thing was i changed to using it as an object "var DashboardCtrl = angular.module('saApp').controller()" or even what i had it to prior to that from the yeoman generator, and specified in the angularjs docs of:

```
angular.module( 'saApp' )
.controller( 'DashboardCtrl', function ( $scope, dataset ) {});
```

with a route of:

```
.when( '/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
        } )
```

wouldn't work.

Comment: did u tried using angular 1.0.5

Comment: just gave it a go, same error

Comment: I'm stuck on this too! I want to reference a controller method in the route.resolve property in the 2nd argument of $routeProvider.when(). How can i do when using the module-style of controller definition? (also using yeoman) I'm stuck!

Comment: I got a similar error when using CoffeeScript `module ($provide) -> $provide.provider 'XX', -> $get: -> "something"` as CoffeeScript returns the last value, which was being misinterpreted by the injector.  I added a `null` after the statement to resolve.

Comment: The error happens due controller gets an object instead of a function. I had this problem because ES6 class have been declared without "export default".

Answer (score 8):

I had this error many times and finally found the perfect and simple solution. Just put your controller name in the 'when' construction into quotes like this:

```
.when( '/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'Dashboard',
    resolve: Dashboard.resolve
}
```

instead of

```
.when( '/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
    controller: Dashboard,
    resolve: Dashboard.resolve
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This returns the controller object:

```
var myCtrl = myApp.controller('whatever'...
```

But route wants the actual controller function. So.... assuming this is your controller and resolve:  (notice i named the controller 'IndexCtrl'... i dont think you were doing that in your code)

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp')

var IndexCtrl = myApp.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope){ 
   .. blah blah... 
})
IndexCtrl.resolve = {
  loadData:function(){ ... blah blah... }
}
```

You can the have angular look up the controller by passing in the name. (notice the controller reference is a string)

```
.when('/',{controller:'IndexCtrl', resolve:IndexCtrl.resolve})
```

Answer (score 4):

Will also happen if you accidentally include extra parenthesis when you link in your factory:

BAD:

```
myModule.factory('monkey', ['$http', MonkeyFactory()]);
```

GOOD:

```
myModule.factory('monkey', ['$http', MonkeyFactory]);
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly it for me - I left off the `MonkeyFactory` entirely as an oversight, but this got me started looking down the right path.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You can resolve it by doing the following..

Remove the controller declaration from the routes .when()
 method. So this...

```
.when( '/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: Dashboard,
        resolve: Dashboard.resolve
    }
```

becomes just this...

```
 .when( '/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        resolve: Dashboard.resolve
    }
```

Now to maintain your scope, add the controller declaration in your html template. For example..

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">{{Some fancy dashboard stuff}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you by mistake did the injection after the name of the factory/controller like this (The wrong way);

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .factory('MyFactory', 'AnotherFactory', ['$http', function($http, AnotherFactory){
        // CODE HERE
    }]);
```

The right way;

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .factory('MyFactory', ['$http', 'AnotherFactory', function($http, AnotherFactory){
        // CODE HERE
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while doing module-mocking with Karma in Coffeescript.

The solution was to add "return null" to the end of the ($provide)-> function.  Without that, coffeescript will return the result of $provide.value(), which I guess is an object, which somehow causes "'fn is not a function".

Example:

```
module 'myModule', ($provide)->
  $provide.value 'myInjectable',
    myFunction:-> return "dummy value"
  return null # prevents "fn is not a function"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this "fn is not a function, got object" by importing my 'function' from another file by adding {} like this:

```
import {MenuCtrl} from './controllers/MenuCtrl.js';
```

old way:

```
import MenuCtrl from './controllers/MenuCtrl.js';
```

Referenced this issue: https://github.com/swimlane/angular-data-table/issues/189

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I forgot to export a class I was importing

```
import MyService from './services/MyService'
app.service('MyService', MyService);
```

MyService.js

```
class MyService(){
    // ... do stuff
}
```

needed to be

```
export default class MyService(){
    // ... do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also happen if you're using Coffescript + angularjs.

Since angularjs supports Coffescript classes.

```
class IndexCtrl 
    constructor: () ->

myApp.controller('IndexCtrl',IndexCtrl)
```

then in the 
.when()

the 'controller: IndexCtrl'  sees an Object, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

We also get this error when we have a function in html which is not defined in controller.